# D3.js - Plotting time series data - Format x-axis from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, plot

I plot very simple data from a JSON file: I need help format my x-date-axis.
I don't know how to specify the date format from the JSON-File for d3.js. I tried the following:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;
```

The JSON data looks like this:

```
var data = [
{"mytime": 20150801, "tt": 17.0}, 
{"mytime": 20150802, "tt": 17.6},
];
```

The result on the x-axis is not as expected. Find my fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/1m1qm6pv/1/

Problem i think is this:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.mytime = parseDate(d.mytime);
});
```

With these 3 lines of code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "dates" are numbers and hence cannot be parsed into Date objects. To parse them, use strings instead of numbers:

```
var data = [
  {"mytime": "20150801", "tt": 17.0}, 
  {"mytime": "20150802", "tt": 17.6},
];
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1m1qm6pv/2/).

Comment: How would you connect line between points in your demo, to make it appear continuous?

Comment: Thanks!, It worked,Trying to add a data legend to the line it's not working. when added attribute like this:
                .attr("data-legend","city")
                .attr('stroke', 'green')

Comment: I have pasted my complete problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086656/changing-size-of-ticks-on-y-axis-and-adding-legend-in-d3-js