# Changing size of ticks on y axis and adding legend in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new D3 and i am trying to draw multiple plots based on incoming data. Here i have tried plotting one of them and will add 4 more like these on the same page. 
Following is my code so far:

```
var data = [
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:10:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:15:00.000Z", "value": 67},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:20:00.000Z", "value": 70},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:25:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:30:00.000Z", "value": 72},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:35:00.000Z", "value": 75},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:40:00.000Z", "value": 71},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:45:00.000Z", "value": 80}
];


var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40, left:50 };

var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;

console.log("1")
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;
data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.mytime = parseDate(d.mytime);
        });

var x_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){
    return d.mytime});
console.log("2")
var y_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){
    return d.value});

var x_scale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(x_extent)
    .range([0,width]);

console.log("3")

var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,y_extent[1]])
    .range([height,0]);



//Line
var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
        console.log(d.date)
        return x_scale(d.mytime);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return y_scale(d.value);
    });

var myChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                .style('background', '#E7E0CB')
                .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ margin.top +')')
                .append('svg:path')
                .datum(data)
                .attr('class', 'line')
                .attr("d",lineGen)
                .attr("data-legend","pulse")
                .attr('stroke', 'green')
                .attr('stroke-width', 0.5)
                .attr('fill', 'none');





var vGuideScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,y_extent[1]])
    .range([height, 0])

var vAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(vGuideScale)
    .orient('left')
//    .tickFormat("") //For removing values
    .ticks(5)
var vGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
    vAxis(vGuide)
    vGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
    vGuide.selectAll('path')
        .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: "#000"})
    vGuide.selectAll('line')
        .style({ stroke: "#000"})

console.log("4")
d3.select('svg').append('g')
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y",6)
      .attr("x",-50)
      .attr("dy", ".51em")
      .attr("font-size", "10px")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("fill", "green")
      .text("Value");

console.log("5")
var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x_scale)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(d3.time.minute, 5);

var hGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
    hAxis(hGuide)
    hGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (height + margin.top) + ')')
    hGuide.selectAll('path')
        .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: "#000"})
    hGuide.selectAll('line')
        .style({ stroke: "#000"})
```

I have few doubts regarding formatting of the code:

1. How to add legend to the code when i tried the following link but i am getting error on using the call function
   http://bl.ocks.org/ZJONSSON/3918369
2. How to reduce reduce tick size on y axis?

Thanks

Comment: Q1: Please, provide a jsfiddle with the legend problems

Comment: You can control the size of the axis font with css: `.axis { font: 10px sans-serif; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is to use css to control the style of your components (including font sizes).  For instance, for all fonts in your SVG tag:

```
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

Second, building a legend can be pretty simple:

```
var legend = myChart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 5 + "," + (height - 25) + ")")

legend.append("rect")
  .style("fill", "green")
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 20);

legend.append("text")
  .text("My Awesome Legend Item")
  .attr("x", 25)
  .attr("y", 12);
```

---

Full code sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    svg {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = [{
      "mytime": "2015-12-01T11:10:00.000Z",
      "value": 64
    }, {
      "mytime": "2015-12-01T11:15:00.000Z",
      "value": 67
    }, {
      "mytime": "2015-12-01T11:20:00.000Z",
      "value": 70
    }, {
      "mytime": "2015-12-01T11:25:00.000Z",
      "value": 64
    }, {
      "mytime": "2015-12-01T11:30:00.000Z",
      "value": 72
    }, {
      "mytime": "2015-12-01T11:35:00.000Z",
      "value": 75
    }, {
      "mytime": "2015-12-01T11:40:00.000Z",
      "value": 71
    }, {
      "mytime": "2015-12-01T11:45:00.000Z",
      "value": 80
    }];


    var margin = {
      top: 30,
      right: 30,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 50
    };

    var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;

    console.log("1")
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.mytime = parseDate(d.mytime);
    });

    var x_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.mytime
    });
    console.log("2")
    var y_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.value
    });

    var x_scale = d3.time.scale()
      .domain(x_extent)
      .range([0, width]);

    console.log("3")

    var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, y_extent[1]])
      .range([height, 0]);



    //Line
    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        console.log(d.date)
        return x_scale(d.mytime);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y_scale(d.value);
      });

    var myChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .style('background', '#E7E0CB')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');
    
    myChart
      .append('svg:path')
      .datum(data)
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr("d", lineGen)
      .attr("data-legend", "pulse")
      .attr('stroke', 'green')
      .attr('stroke-width', 0.5)
      .attr('fill', 'none');

    var legend = myChart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + 5 + "," + (height - 25) + ")")
    
    legend.append("rect")
      .style("fill", "green")
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20);
      
    legend.append("text")
      .text("My Awesome Legend Item")
      .attr("x", 25)
      .attr("y", 12);

    var vGuideScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, y_extent[1]])
      .range([height, 0])

    var vAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(vGuideScale)
      .orient('left')
      //    .tickFormat("") //For removing values
      .ticks(5)
    var vGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g').attr("class", "y axis")
    vAxis(vGuide)
    vGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')

    console.log("4")
    d3.select('svg').append('g')
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("x", -50)
      .attr("dy", ".51em")
      .attr("font-size", "10px")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("fill", "green")
      .text("Value");

    console.log("5")
    var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x_scale)
      .orient('bottom')
      .ticks(d3.time.minute, 5);

    var hGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g').attr("class", "x axis")
    hAxis(hGuide)
    hGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (height + margin.top) + ')')
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Mark , Thanks for the answer !! It works !! but for understanding I was trying this link initially but it's not working for me http://bl.ocks.org/ZJONSSON/3918369. Can you explain how to go about implementing this ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the length of the ticks via the [tickSize setter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickSize)
Like this:

```
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scale)
    .orient("right")
    .ticks(2)
    .tickSize(10)
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);
```

and then:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(axis);
```

Comment: Hey , Thanks for the reply! I meant the number which appears next to the ticks (ex. 0,10,20,30 etc). I will provide the jsfiddle shortly. I tried right now and for some reason the data is not displayed in that.